# F# - Seq.iter (type error)

Tags: types, f#

I have the follow function with multiple inputs

```
let blackscholes strike assetPrice standarddev riskfreerate days2expiration c_p =
```

And I would like to Seq.iter it so that it is evaluated for multiple values of assetPrice, while holding everything else constant. I am wondering about the syntax, do I have to create an intermediate version of the function that takes only one argument? i.e.

```
let blackscholesTemp assetPrice = blackscholes 100. assetPrice 0.2 0.05 60 'c' =
```

When I try that way and do

```
printf "Results:" 
Seq.iter (blackscholesTemp) (seq {0.0..10.0..100.0})
```

I received the error "Type mismatch. Expecting a float -> unit but given a float -> float The type 'unit' does not match the type 'float'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `Seq.map` instead of `Seq.iter` as `Seq.map` returns a sequence of results whilst `Seq.iter` doesn't return a list of results

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem. Gotta find out how to properly use Seq.iter, Seq.map and Seq.choose.